# Determine if a Range contains a value

Tags: swift, range

I'm trying to figure out a way to determine if a value falls within a `Range` in Swift.

Basically what I'm trying to do is adapt one of the switch statement examples to do something like this:

```
let point = (1, -1)
switch point {
case let (x, y) where (0..5).contains(x):
    println("(\(x), \(y)) has an x val between 0 and 5.")
default:
    println("This point has an x val outside 0 and 5.")
}
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't any built in way to do what my imaginary `.contains` method above does.

So I tried to extend the `Range` class. I ended up running into issues with generics though. I can't extend `Range<Int>` so I had to try to extend `Range` itself.

The closest I got was this but it doesn't work since `>=` and `<=` aren't defined for `ForwardIndex`

```
extension Range {
    func contains(val:ForwardIndex) -> Bool {
        return val >= self.startIndex && val <= self.endIndex
    }
}
```

How would I go about adding a `.contains` method to `Range`? Or is there a better way to determine whether a value falls within a range?

Edit2: This seems to work to extend `Range`

```
extension Range {
    func contains(val:T) -> Bool {
        for x in self {
            if(x == val) {
                return true
            }
        }

        return false
    }
}

var a = 0..5
a.contains(3) // true
a.contains(6) // false
a.contains(-5) // false
```

I am very interested in the ~= operator mentioned below though; looking into that now.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do it with the `~=` operator:

```
let point = (1, -1)
switch point {
case let (x, y) where (0..5) ~= x:
   println("(\(x), \(y)) has an x val between 0 and 5.")
default:
   println("This point has an x val outside 0 and 5.")
}
```

You can also do it directly in a switch:

```
let point = (1, -1)
let (x, y) = point
switch x {
case 0..5:
    println("yes")
default:
    println("no")
}
```

`~=` is the pattern match operator used by case statements. See details [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-XID_909).

Comment: Interesting; any idea what that operator is called?

Comment: Well, in ruby it is `===` and it is called the "case equality operator", which is a sort of specialized equality with behaviors that make case statements cleaner. So perhaps it's called the same thing here, but I don't know for sure. Unless I'm missing it, it isn't mentioned at all in the Swift operator documentation.

Comment: @BradDwyer It's in Apple's book as the "Pattern match" operator.

Comment: I see you're right. Searching didn't turn it up. It is definitely more than ranges, and I'm 99% sure it is the way `case` is defined. Consider this (sorry for one line): `class Foo {}; switch 3 {case Foo.self: println("foo"); default: println("default")}` which gives the error "could not find an overload for '~=' that accepts the supplied arguments" on `Foo.self` and is fixed if I define `@infix func ~=(left: AnyClass, right: Int) -> Bool`.

Comment: Thanks @0x7fffffff - hadn't made it near that far in the book. Was able to get that to work and also found out how to add an extension to `Range` in a way that made the `==` operator work for type `T` as well. Added that to my original post.

Comment: For what it's worth, it is all documented (re: case statements) here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-XID_909

Answer (score 35):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the following options to determine if a `Range` (or a `ClosedRange`) contains a value.

---

### 1. `contains(_:)` method

`Range`, `ClosedRange`, `CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange` have a `contains(_:)` method. `Range` [`contains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/1641800-contains) method has the following declaration:

```
func contains(_ element: Bound) -> Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the given element is contained within the range.

Usage:

```
let value: Int = 0
let range = -200 ..< 300
print(range.contains(value)) // prints true
```

---

### 2. `~=(_:_:)` operator

`Range`, `ClosedRange`, `CountableRange` and `CountableClosedRange` have a `~=(_:_:)` operator. `Range` [`~=(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range/2428743) operator has the following declaration:

```
static func ~= (pattern: Range<Bound>, value: Bound) -> Bool
```

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether a value is included in a range.

Usage:

```
let value = 0
let range = -200 ..< 300
print(range ~= value) // prints true
```

---

### 3. Switch statement

A simple way to test if a `Range`, a `ClosedRange`, a `CountableRange` or a `CountableClosedRange` contains a value is to use a switch statement:

```
let value = 0
switch value {
case -200 ..< 300:
    print("OK") // prints "OK"
default:
    break
}
```

---

### 4. Pattern matching with `if case`

As an alternative to the previous switch statement, you can use `if case`:

```
let value = 0
if case -200 ..< 300 = value {
    print("OK") // prints "OK"
}
```

---

Therefore, in order to solve your problem, you can use one of the following options:

```
let point = (1, -1)
switch point {
case let (x, y) where (0 ..< 5).contains(x):
    print("(\(x), \(y)) has an x val between 0 and 5.")
default:
    print("This point has an x val outside 0 and 5.")
}
```

```
let point = (1, -1)
if case let (x, y) = point, 0 ..< 5 ~= x {
    print("(\(x), \(y)) has an x val between 0 and 5.")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of messing with Range, you could add a simple helper function like this

```
let point = (1, -1)
switch point {
case let (x, y) where contains((0..5),x):
    println("(\(x), \(y)) has an x val between 0 and 5.")
default:
    println("This point has an x val outside 0 and 5.")
}

func contains(range :Range<Int>, x: Int)->Bool{
    for num in range{
        if(num==x){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

You could also probably do something similar with a closure.

Comment: No need to define the function: `contains()` is (now?) part of the standard library ([ref](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111162737/http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/14/the-swift-standard-library-list-of-built-in-functions/))!

Comment: Because you can never have enough global functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write `contains` extension of `Range`, use `distanceTo` of `ForwardIndex` to determine if given value falls within range.

Also use specific type `Element` instead of general protocol `FowardIndex` as parameter's type.

Both `distanceTo` and `Element` are part of `Range` definition.

```
extension Range {

    func contains(element: Element) -> Bool {
        return startIndex.distanceTo(element) >= 0 && element.distanceTo(endIndex) > 0
    }

}
```

Plus `Range` already has a `contains` method from `extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable`. So you can just use it without writing one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at the same thing and did:

```
let r = 7...9

operator infix ~ {}
func ~ (range:Range<Int>, item:Int) -> Bool{
  return item >= range.startIndex  && item <= range.endIndex - 1
}

r ~ 9
```

then I saw that ~= does the same thing!